# Cycle through objects inside an object

Tags: c#

I have a class `Alarms` that contains multiples `Lists` of different models. Every model is different and they are composed of multiple string properties. My goal is to create a CSV file, per model, but without harcoding every single string property in my model.

```
public class Alarms
{
   public List<SectorA> SectorA { get; set; } = new List<SectorA>();
   public List<SectorB> SectorB { get; set; } = new List<SectorB>();
   public List<SectorC> SectorC { get; set; } = new List<SectorC>();
}
```

I found a way to cycle through the string properties, like this:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in alarms.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
    if (type == typeof(string))
    {
        line += $"{prop.GetValue(lines, null)};";
    }
}
```

My question is **how can I cycle through my `Alarm` class to get every `List<SectorX>` inside of it in one loop** ?

Edit:
Example of one `SectorX` class

```
public class SectorA
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Edit#2
Here is the function that I have to loop through a class to get its properties

```
public void WriteCsv<T>(string csvOutputPath, List<object> sectors)
{
    using (var w = new StreamWriter(csvOutputPath))
    {
        foreach (var lines in sectors)
        {
            string line = "";
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in lines.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
                if (type == typeof(string))
                {
                    line += $"{prop.GetValue(lines, null)};";
                }
            }

            line = line.Remove(line.Length - 1);

            w.WriteLine(line);
            w.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you plan to use all this lists?

Comment: I want to cycle through every row and create a separated CSV file for them. Example, in folder `Alarm_Name`, I will have 3 CSVs, `sector1.csv`, `sector2.csv`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best way but

```
private void Test(object item)
{
    var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        object value = prop.GetValue(item);
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) && value != null)
        // if (prop.PropertyType.IsInterface && value != null)
        {
            foreach (var iItem in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(iItem.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RegularNormalDayGuy your properties are `List`'s, not `SectorA`.....

Comment: That's true, but my code does not enter the if block, and I know there is at least one value inside `value`

Comment: That will probably work, but what is the harm of using `IsClass` ?

Comment: No it did not work. I have a hard time with the signature of my function `WriteCsv`, I cannot convert `object` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<object>`. I cannot change it object, since then I won't be able to iterate through its properties

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the GetFields() Method can help here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type objType = typeof(Alarms);

            BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public |
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                            BindingFlags.Instance |
                            BindingFlags.Static;

            FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = objType.GetFields(bindingFlags);

            for (int i = 0; i < fieldInfos.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(" {0}", fieldInfos[i]);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

public class Alarms
{
    public List<SectorA> SectorA { get; set; } = new List<SectorA>();
}

public class SectorA
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```